# Why account creation using CALL or SUICIDE costs 25000 gas?

Tags: accounts, gas-price, protocol

CALL and SUICIDE both have additional cost of 25000 gas if it leads to account creation.
At the same time, sending 1 wei in separate transaction costs only 21000 gas.
Thereby if I am about to create account using CALL or SUICIDE, I'd better send 1 wei in separate transaction to that account and only after that do my CALL/SUICIDE stuff.
These two transactions will cost me 4000 gas less, however they will for sure generate more waste for blockchain to store.

Is there any reason for account creation pricing to be designed in such contradictory way?

Comment: @Ismael why do you think the question is duplicate?